# Javascript compilation error when trying to import react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, compiler-errors

Code:
// React and react components
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import App from './containers/App'

Error Message: "Syntax error 800A03EA at line 2"

I got the whole project from https://github.com/mimshwright/mimstris
and changed nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which program is telling the error message? Which command did you use?

Comment: I just double clicked the main.js The program telling the error message is Windows Script host. When I am opening the index.html everything loads except the main.js, which is embeded in the .html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @YTKSnieSnie any progress?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run main.js because this is the source code. You need build the application first and therefore you need build tools.
In this case install [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) and after installing dependent modules (`yarn install`) you can start the application in development mode (`yarn run start`) or build it (`yarn run build`).